# How to print URL-Variables in HTML on my Website?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to print a Variable from my URL to my Website. 
E.g. https://example.com/?firstname=john&secondname=smith

Now I would like to print that on my website in a lable like:

```html
<lable>Your Firstname is: </lable> <!-- +Firstname -->
```

I also added a Script to get the Variable from the URL by using getQueryVariable('firstname');

```html
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
</script>
```

This works fine for me... but I would like to print the result on my website. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use framework to embed the value in the HTML code or using selectors like by id, by class, by HTML node etc. google "select HTML elements JS"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look. This might help you

```js
// Assuming "?post=1234&action=edit"

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

console.log(urlParams.has('post')); // true
console.log(urlParams.get('action')); // "edit"
console.log(urlParams.getAll('action')); // ["edit"]
console.log(urlParams.toString()); // "?post=1234&action=edit"
console.log(urlParams.append('active', '1')); // "?post=1234&action=edit&active=1"
```